# Gedit preferences option do not show up under normal user(i was able to customize it under root user.)

Tags: gedit, gnome-3, fedora-25

I am using fedora 25,  gedit - Version 3.22.0

Gedit preferences option do not show up under normal user(i was able to customize it under root user.)

I tried changing all the following folders permissions to normal user from root(using chmon)...  but still nothing positive happened..

```
/usr/bin/gedit  
/usr/lib64/gedit
/usr/libexec/gedit
/usr/share/gedit
/usr/share/man/man1/gedit.1.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

> i was able to customize it under root user.

Don't run graphical applications as root.

> tried changing all the following folders permissions to normal user from root(using chmon)...

Don't randomly change permissions on system files.

Anyway we need more information, what preferences don't show up, what is printed to the terminal when you run `gedit`, etc.

Comment: I want to turn gedit as a good IDE, so I tried to install few plugins like auto completion, braces completion and so on. But in order to activate them I need to have access to preferences tab which was not present anywhere in option of gedit for normal user which can be found while im using it from root user.  Finally, I installed Atom. Which is working good for my needs...

Comment: On Gnome the preferences menu entry is in the top left of the shell.